# What is the difference between CMake and GMake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, gnu-make

I am currently working on a project which requires me to learn about CMake and GMake. I read about them but still don't get their applications.

Can someone provide a few examples of how CMake and GMake are used in software development?

Thank You.

Comment: You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/q/39761924/2799037

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`make` or [`gmake`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#Top) uses `Makefile`s to describe how to build your code. A `Makefile` contains targets and recipes. A target can be an object file or executable and the recipe is how to produce that target.

`cmake` is a higher level language with the same purpose but with a higher level of abstraction. With `cmake` you can generate ordinary `Makefiles` or files for other build systems, such as Ninja etc.

Comment: So every `Makefile` written with `gmake` can be executed with `cmake` but not viceversa?

Comment: @baggiponte `Makefile`s are written _for_ `make`/`gmake` (which means that they can be parsed by `make`/`gmake`). `cmake` parses `CMakeLists.txt` files and _generates_ `Makefile`s (or `Ninja` files for example) that can then be parsed by `make`/`gmake` (or `Ninja`).

Answer (score 4):

CMake is used to generate a project, it does not compile nor create object files, but generates files that will be used by other softwares such as GNU make (GMake). It uses `CMakeLists.txt` files for configuration.

GMake is the name for GNU make which is basically the `make` command on Linux (https://linux.die.net/man/1/gmake). It uses `Makefile` files for configuration.